# Showing that $\mathbb{R}^2/\sim$ is Hausdorff where $x\sim y \iff$ $(x=y\,\, \text{or}\,\, x,y \in $ $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\,\,|\,\, |y|\leq e^x\}$)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-writing

> The topological space of this problem is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608480/fundamental-group-and-doubt-about-covering-map) question I asked yesterday.
> Let $Y=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\,\,|\,\, |y|\leq e^x\}$ and define $W=\mathbb{R}^2/\sim$, where $x\sim y \iff (x=y\,\,\,\, \text{or}\,\, x,y \in Y)$ . Show $W$ is Hausdorff.

First of all, I considered $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\to W$. Clearly, since the domain is Hausdorff and $\pi$ is continuous, we can't conclude $\pi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is Hausdorff. So I thought to prove it "manually", taking two points of $W$ and showing they are separable. The problem of this approach comes when I consider $[(0,0)] \in W$.

I am looking forward to a hint.

Comment: Remove a point on the boundary of the circle that isn't in the $x + y < 1$ part, and note that the fundamental group remains trivial.

Comment: Don't ask two distinct questions in the same post.

Comment: @DavidLui Thank you, I surely have to study better the part of algebraic topology. I'll remove the first part since I am not allowed to post two different question in the same post

Comment: @AnneBauval Indeed I was not aware of this rule. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Furthermore in $W$ we have:

$$[v]=\begin{cases}
\{v\}&\text{if }v\not\in Y \\
Y&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

So how do we utilize this information? How to separate $[v]$ from $[w]$?

1. If both $v,w\not\in Y$ then they can be separated in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in such a way that both neighborhoods are disjoint from $Y$. That's because $Y$ is closed. In such situation they are mapped via $\pi$ to open, disjoint neighborhoods in $W$.
2. If one of them belongs to $Y$, say $w$, then we simply separate $v$ from $Y$. This can be done since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is regular. Then we again directly map those neighborhoods via $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a method without using regular spaces, since i didn't study them?

Comment: @SineoftheTime sure. You can take some positive real $r$ such that $B(v,r)$ is disjoint from $Y$. Then the open neighborhoods are: $B(v,r/2)$ and $r/2$-neighborhood of $Y$ (i.e. the union of all $B(y,r/2)$ over $y\in Y$).

Comment: This was my concern. I thought this way, but I was stuck choosing an open neighbourhood in the quotient space. Clearly, 2 points satisfying your second case are separable in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, can I choose the union of the balls in the quotient space?

Comment: @SineoftheTime choose union in $\mathbb{R}^2$, say $U$. Then the neighborhood in $W$ is $\pi(U)$. It is open because $U=\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))$. Analogously for the neighborhood of $[u]$.